# Display long text in fixed frame in Corona

Tags: coronasdk

so at the moment I have to do an assignment at school which requires me to create a Calculator for mobile devices using Corona, ive got the buttons and display classes to work.

In the display class, Ive created 2 frame (one to display the method and the others for result). The final result im looking for is something like a handheld graphical calculator's UI (Casio fx series..).

Which means you can type in a long and continuous method (the whole text will move toe the left and always show you the END of the method) as you press "=" the calculator will give you the result.

What I've got up to so far is that I created a frame which can fit 2 lines of text for displaying the method, but once you've filled up the frame with numbers, Corona will crop out the end of the string .

---

so what i'm going to do is by having 2 strings, the 1st one is the main one to store what the user type in (the whole method) I will select the last 10 characters from the main string and save it in the second string and display the second string.

So do you know if there's any code that i can use to select a number of characters from a string ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in LUA method

```
string.sub (yourString, startIndex , endIndex )
```

http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/string.sub`